# Is there any way to make a set from string in kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin.
I want to make a `Set` from a `String` in Kotlin. For example

```
val myStr = "oop"
```

Will be a **[o,p]** as `Set`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `toSet()`.

```
val mSet = "oop".toSet()

Log.d(TAG, mSet.toString()) //[o, p]
```